# How to remove blue outline from input element that is focused?

Tags: css, google-chrome

```css
input {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

I wouldn't like to display that ugly blue border(in Chrome) when focusing the input, but I don't know how to achive that.

Comment: Try adding outline: none; - it removes it for me in Chrome

Answer (score 4):

Change your CSS to

```
input{
height:60px;
margin:30px;    
border-radius: 20px;
outline:none;
}
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y8jpvh50/